# Using const in getters in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am having a hard time understanding this purpose of const at the end of the getter declaration. What purpose it has here?

```
// Define getter
std::string Car::brand() const
{
    return _brand;
}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What `const` does is always the same in C++. In this case it's a guarantee that your getter cannot alter state.

Comment: Except for elements declared mutable

Comment: The getter function should have only one responsibility (getting a certain value) so the const keyword makes sure that u won't change anything in the class. Meaning u can get a value but u can't change the state of the class. By the state I mean member variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `const` specifier serves the purpose of clarifying what this method is allowed to do. If a member function is declared `const`, you can be sure that it is not going to modify any members of that instance.

Comment: @MrNullPointer And to explain what it allows you to do. It allows you to call the method when a `Car` instance is const, while omitting const on the method will give you a compile error when a `Car` instance is const.

Comment: Oh! I love these nitty gritty details of C++. Everything has a purpose and that's what makes it so powerful. Thank you for letting me know. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @MrNullPointer • pre-C++11 `const` member functions guarantee that they do not modify the *logical state* of the object.  C++11 and later, `const` member functions guarantee that they do not modify the *logical state* of the object *in a thread-safe manner*.